# Merge tables together without column headers? Python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, for-loop

I have an Excel workbook with multiple sheets. I need to loop through each sheet and get the same certain columns from each sheet and combine them. I am struggling to

1.Combine and store the tables together
, 2. Get rid of the column headers after the first table is looped through.

This is what I currently have

```
sheets = ["sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"]
df1 = pd.read_excel("Blank.xlsx")
for x in sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel("Final.xlsx", sheetname=x, skiprows=1, header='true')
    y = df[['Col1','Col2', 'Col3','Col4', 'Col5']]
    print(y)
```

Bonus:
storing everything back into an excel sheet.

I currently have tried to do use a blank workbook to pd.merge whatever is being looped through with the blank excel but it's not working. Help!

Comment: I feel like converting the excel sheet to a CSV file would make this easier, or using SQL

Comment: Look up `pd.concat(..,axis=1) # or axis=0`

Comment: use pandas to_excel function.. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html